# timeago vs cutetime vs prettydate

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Which one of the "timeago or cutetime or prettydate" jquery plugin is better performance wise for displaying fuzzy dates.

I require both historic times and futuristic ones, like Posted 5 days ago, or like Expiring in 5 days.

It should auto update all the date references after every set interval, say a minute.

And it may work in different languages, and timezones, and may allow for sorting of formatted dates.

I know its too much to ask, but I am willing to modify a plugin as per my requirement, so want to pick a plugin which is better in performance, can someone guide.

Regards

Comment: jQuery timediff (http://plugins.jquery.com/timediff/) ;) Honestly, that is subjective and hard to measure. Pick smallest, most popular and review the choice if it does not fit your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have built jQuery timediff module (http://plugins.jquery.com/timediff/), which seems to match your requirements:

- it is small (full source is around 80 lines, most of which is actual difference calculation),
- it relies on JS Date object to parse timestamp,
- allows to set update interval,
- handles dates in the past and in the future,
- is extensible/pluggable by default,
- formatted dates are stored as text in the tag (thus you can sort them),
- its code is on GitHub in non-minified version (https://github.com/tadeck/timediff/blob/master/jquery.timediff.js) with documentation,

Maybe you would like to try it. It may fit your needs (it fits your requirements), but is not so huge and complex as some other modules with similar goals.